# create string with calloc

Tags: c, string, malloc, calloc

I'm trying to create a string with a simply calloc, but i don't understand why this code works. This calloc would have to create a string with only one space to put only a char, right? Why, when i try to print my string, on stdout i see value casted to string? I thought on stdout appeared only the first number, because I have allocated with calloc only one space.

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    char* string;
    int value=6000031;
    string=calloc(1,sizeof(char));
    sprintf(string,"%d",value);
    printf("%s\n",string);
    free(string);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Writing to invalid memory is Undefined Behaviour. There is no need to try and reason with Undefined Behaviour. Appearing to work is the one of the hardest things for beginners to understand about UB (at some point code containing UB will break even if it sometimes "works"). Bottom line is that UB is always wrong. Just fix it and move on.

Comment: You are allocating space for 1 `char`, so `string` only has enough legal space to hold a null terminator.  Your `sprint()` call is going to exceed the bounds of `string` and overwrite surrounding memory. The `printf()` *works* because it is processing the output from `sprintf()`, which is valid data, even though the memory is not valid. If you get far enough to call `printf()` in the first place (your app hasn't crashed outright), the corrupted memory did belong to your app in some form, but of course you corrupted it, so you don't know what you app will do once `sprint()` has finished.

Comment: You need enough space in the string for each digit as a separate character plus a null terminator.  That means the two arguments to `calloc()` must multiply to at least `8` to be safe (for the given data) — whereas you've only allocated `1` byte of data, which is very inadequate.  Or you could use `snprintf(string, 1, "%d", value)`, though you'd only get the null terminator and no digits.

Comment: It is not keeping track of how much space you allocated.  That's your job.  If you write past it, *anything* can happen.  No one wants to waste their time analyzing it.  Fix your known bugs, *then* if you're having problems ask for help.

Comment: Why `calloc` instead of `malloc`?

Comment: Note also that when you allocate memory, the actual buffer allocated might be larger than what you requested. This can lead to UB problems to appear to work without consequence, which could be the case here -- but it's a trap because you will find such errors that appear to work will break when you don't expect them to, and at a time where you have no idea what the cause might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sprintf` will try to write the whole value to the string array.  It doesn't know the size of the memory.  You end up writing into invalid memory.  It just so happens you're not causing a seg fault.

Use `snprintf` with a size of 1, but it would always return an empty string in that case.  If you are just trying to pull off the first character, use `snprintf(string, 2, "%d", value);` and increase the `calloc` size to 2 bytes.  (One for the NUL character at the end)

Comment: @FiddlingBits:  What am I missing?